# Problem Creating a struct within my script in Matlab

Tags: matlab, struct

I am trying to write a variable into a structure and read it from another existing structure:

`struct1.vector = struct2.matrix(:,1);`

when I run this line in my script it will create a double variable struct1. Thats why I will get the error:

> Unable to perform assignment because dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.

When I just run the same line in my Command Window it will create a struct variable struct1 just as I want to. Also there are multiple lines, where I try to write into struct1 and some times the first 4 lines work and the 5th doesn't.
I don't understand why the script is creating a double, can anybody help me with this?

Help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: hello and welcome to stackoverflow. please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That probably means that you already have a variable named `struct1` in your workspace, either leftover from some previous activity, or assigned earlier in the script.

You can make sure you have a fresh workspace by calling `clear` before running your script. Better yet, turn your script into a function, and it will have its own workspace.

You can also replace the whole `struct1` variable with a new empty struct, to make sure it's of the right type, before assigning to its fields.

```
struct1 = struct;
struct1.vector = struct2.matrix(:,1);
```

Comment: I just tried it, but the error remains. There is no other struct with the same name.

Comment: @downbydawn: That's not possible, please post a [mre] in your question so we can see what exactly you are doing.

Comment: I found a variable that was accidentally assigned the same way, changed it and it works now. Thank you!